# Set JList indices to separate Strings

Tags: arrays, jlist

I have a `JList` in my program, and would like to know how to set each index to a `String`. I then use that to update an SQL database by using a regex array with the `String` that splits the it into three values that pertain to the SQL database columns.

I have an idea on how to do this, but, I would imagine that there is a much more efficient way to complete this.

```
int indices = JList.getLastVisibleIndex();+1;
int stringnum = 0;

//getLastVisibleIndex returns the integer of items I have in the JList, 
but if I have 5, the value is returned 4, etc, so I add 1. 
A more efficient way of doing this is possible, I would also imagine?

while(stringnum<indices){
    JList.setSelectedIndex(1);
    String item = JList.getSelectedIndex();
    //Where I use the string (I'm updating an SQL database using it)
    remove(item);
    //Remove is a method I have set up to remove the selected index
    stringnum++;
}
```

I haven't actually tested the above code out, but I would imagine it would work; I just thought I would ask here if there were a better way anyone knew how to approach my problem. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I tested my code. It worked. But I'd still like to know if there were a cleaner way to execute this. It also will only delete items that are absolutely visible, not the ones beyond the scroll pane. I'll look for a way to fix that.